# API request is capping at 10 images

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, api-design

I am currently working on a project which pulls from the Harvard Museum API, specifically images of paintings. These images will last on the screen for 90 seconds, before transitioning to a new image.

Everything is working smoothly in regards to the actual pulling of the image and putting it onto our web-page, but after 10 images the process stops and it stays on the 10th image.

Below is the javascript my colleague wrote, minus our API key which I have left out. Any help is greatly appreciated!

````
var queryString = $.param({
    apikey: " ___ ",
    classification: "Paintings"
});

$.getJSON(apiEndpointBaseURL + "?" + queryString, function(genpics) {


    let records = genpics.records;
    for (let index = 0; index < records.length; index++) {
        const element = records[index];
        
        let artistName = document.querySelector("#artist");
        
        console.log(genpics.records[index].images[0].baseimageurl);

    }
    
    let pictureImg = document.querySelector(".picture");
    pictureImg.setAttribute("src", genpics.records[0].images[0].baseimageurl);
    let currentRecordIndex = 1;
    setInterval(function() {
        let currentRecord = genpics.records[currentRecordIndex];
        pictureImg.setAttribute("src", currentRecord.images[0].baseimageurl);
        currentRecordIndex++;
    }, 90000)

});```
````

Comment: Are there are errors thrown?

Comment: Yes, the error is thrown on the attempt to load an 11th image after the 10th. The error thrown is: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'images' of undefined
    at dougs.js:36"